# MuPAD - rearrange an equation

Tags: matlab, computer-algebra-systems

I have a huge expression, say $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0,$  and I want MuPAD to try to express $x_1 $ in terms of $x_2$ and $x_3$ Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `solve`, which is a [general solver for symbolic equalities and inequalities](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/solve.html). Here's an example:

```
f:=x1^2+x2^2+x3^2=0
solve(f,x1)
```

which returns two solutions, as expected:

```
{-(- x2^2 - x3^2)^(1/2), (- x2^2 - x3^2)^(1/2)}
```

This may ore may not work for your equation that you didn't provide. I recommend reading the documentation for `solve` carefully, trying the examples, and learning about the various options.

MuPAD's `solve` is very similar to the `solve` available directly within Matlab's symbolic Math toolbox ([see documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html)). So you could also solve the above example via:

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f = x1^2+x2^2+x3^2==0
solve(f,x1)
```